# Returning values to other functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to figure out how to use variables from one function in another one. I can't seem to use the return command correctly. All help is appreciated! Here is an example of what I want:

{

```
def a():
    num1 = input("number: ")
    return num1
def b():
    str1 = input("letter :")
    return str1
def main():
    a()
    b()
    print(num1,str1)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
   def main():
        print(a(),b())
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply assign the returned values to variables in `main()`, and don't forget to add a return statement in `b()`. By default a function returns `None` in Python.

```
def a():
    num1 = input("number: ")
    return num1

def b():
    str1 = input("letter :")
    return str1

def main():
    num1 = a()      #here you can use any variable name, not necessarily `num1`
    str1 = b()      #here you can use any variable name, not necessarily `str1`
    print(num1,str1)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> main()
number: 10
letter :a
10 a
```

Comment: Thanks, is here a way I can have them print values without redefining them in the main function?

Comment: Yes, there is `global`, but going that way will lead you down to code hell.

Comment: @user2951303 Yes you can use `print(a(), b())`, this would directly print the returned values.